# Is it good idea to use Subject for notifying other components to do an action in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an Angular app with nofications component, where I use service to create get request to the api on some interval of time in order to recieve new notifications and show them in the component. I want to add feature which after adding new item to create new request for the notifications, so not to wait for the interval to come. The idea which comes me in mind was to add a subject in the service and emmit values from the items component when new item is added. Then I subscribe in the notifications component to the service and when new value is recieved I call the notifications service which makes the request. I am not so familiar with Angular and will be glad to hear is this idea suitable for the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is what Observables are for, you emit a value and all the subscribers react to a value being emitted.

Comment: Yes, but what bothers me is the fact that the value I emmit is never used.

Comment: Then just emit without a value. const subject$ = new Subject<void>(); subject$.next();